# How do I filter a GFF file by gene type?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with following information:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    135141  135895  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000268903.1"; gene_type "processed_pseudogene"; gene_name "AL627309.7"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000182518.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    137682  137965  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000269981.1"; gene_type "processed_pseudogene"; gene_name "AL627309.8"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000182738.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    139790  140339  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000239906.1"; gene_type "antisense_RNA"; gene_name "AL627309.2"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002481.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    141474  173862  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000241860.6"; gene_type "processed_transcript"; gene_name "AL627309.5"; level 2; tag "ncRNA_host"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002480.3";
chr1    ENSEMBL gene    157784  157887  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000222623.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "RNU6-1100P"; level 3;
chr1    HAVANA  gene    160446  161525  .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000241599.1"; gene_type "lincRNA"; gene_name "AL627309.4"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002525.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    182696  184174  .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000279928.2"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "FO538757.2"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000191962.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    185217  195411  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000279457.4"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "FO538757.1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000191963.1";
```

In the above file there is a `gene_type` with different names like processed_pseudogene, lincRNA, snRNA, unprocessed_pseudogene, antisense_RNA, processed_transcript.

I want to create a new file based on `gene_type`. Among all the gene_types I want the new file to be with certain names of `gene_type` like only processed_pseudogene, lincRNA, unprocessed_pseudogene, antisense_RNA.

The new file should look like below:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    135141  135895  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000268903.1"; gene_type "processed_pseudogene"; gene_name "AL627309.7"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000182518.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    137682  137965  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000269981.1"; gene_type "processed_pseudogene"; gene_name "AL627309.8"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000182738.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    139790  140339  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000239906.1"; gene_type "antisense_RNA"; gene_name "AL627309.2"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002481.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    160446  161525  .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000241599.1"; gene_type "lincRNA"; gene_name "AL627309.4"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000002525.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    182696  184174  .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000279928.2"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "FO538757.2"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000191962.1";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    185217  195411  .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000279457.4"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "FO538757.1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000191963.1";
```

Comment: your algorithm to create a file is not clear. please clear your question

Comment: Don't you have some bioinformatics tool that filters GFF files on gene type?

Comment: No, I dont have any. Are there any tools for filtering on gene_type? Could you please recommend me some.

Comment: @Kusalananda They mention that they want to keep "certain names of `gene_type` like only processed_pseudogene, lincRNA, unprocessed_pseudogene, antisense_RNA"

Comment: @Sparhawk Ah, they edited. I missed that. I still think it should be migrated though. I'm fairly certain there are standard bioinformatics tools for these types of operation on GFF files.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not 100% sure there are, because that 9th field is often just a unregulated dumping ground for "other" characteristics. I'm happy to proven wrong though… it would be most helpful!

Comment: @Sparhawk There are mandatory and optional fields and there are controlled vocabularies for that 9th field, so it nat just "anything goes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -E 'gene_type "(processed_pseudogene|lincRNA|unprocessed_pseudogene|antisense_RNA)";' input_file.txt
```

## Explanation

- `grep -E`: use extended regular expression so you don't need to escape things.
- This kind of expression `(foo|bar|baz)` allows grep to include either of these strings. Hence, the total expression will match `gene_type "processed_pseudogene";'`, `gene_type "lincRNA";'`, etc.